# Good way to handle a whole hierarchy of exceptions on several places

Tags: c++, exception, coding-style

<sub>I'm pretty sure there's similar question around here, but I can't find it.</sub>

Suppose I have several functions, that may throw a whole hierarchy of exceptions - let's say *N* types of exception classes.

Now, is there a nice way to handle all these exceptions, instead of writing several times the same code with *N* `catch`-blocks?

The (very ugly) way I achieve this is using macros. Other ideas?

<sub>all functions are with different input/output parameters and return types</sub>

---

**EDIT**

Yes, all exceptions have the same base class - it's an hierarchy. But the different classes have different additional information.

Example:

```
try
{
    object->execute( ... );
}
catch( type1& ex )
{
    // ...
}
//...
catch( typeN& ex )
{
    // ...
}

// some other code
// and again:

try
{
    object->do_something_else( ... );
}
catch( type1& ex )
{
    // ...
}
//...
catch( typeN& ex )
{
    // ...
}

// and so on
```

Comment: If your exceptions have the same base class, you can write just one handler. It is not clear where do you want to handle exceptions from different fucntions.

Comment: @KirillKobelev - they have the same base class, yes, it'a an hierarchy. But the different classes have different additional information. I'll edit my question for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call of the traget function should have its own try block, unless you can combine these calls into one function with a switch inside.

You can catch the base class and call a common function that will use the `typeid` operation or any other way to distinguish between possible types of exceptions inside. Since exceptions should happen rarely, overhead from using the RTTI might be acceptabe.

Comment: Hm, I like the idea for RTTI. I'll think about that.

Comment: Just make sure to catch by reference, to avoid slicing.

Answer (score 3):

Make a function called `handleExceptions(Exception&)` that takes a reference to a base class of the exceptions.

In that function you can do whatever you wish with the exception, e.g. call some virtual methods that are specific to sub-classes of `Exception`. You can also define what exception actually is with `dynamic_cast` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Capturing by base class and giving the exception to a handleException method, which then switches on the actual underlying type, has already been mentioned. Here is an alternative approch, which goes the other way around:

You could write a function `exception_check`, which takes a functor and executes it nested inside the appropriate `try..catch`:

```
template<typename Func>
Func exception_check(Func fun)
{
    try
    {
        func();
    }
    catch( type1& ex )
    {...}
    //...
    catch( typeN& ex )
    {...}
    return func; //in case the functor stores a result. 
}
```

Of course to make this work without the resulting code looking hideously ugly you probably need C++11 with its lambda functions, since otherwise you would scatter your code over lots of functors. With lambda functions it can simply be called as

```
exception_check([&](){ object->execute(...); }); 
exception_check([&](){ object->do_something_else(...); });
```

Personally I find this nicer to read then having one try/catch around each function call.

Of course in c++11 it might be a good idea to use perfect forwarding for the functor  instead of copying it.

Comment: I can't use C++11, as it's a large project, that is always compiled for an old specific platform (RHEL4 with its original gcc), but this sounds nice. I'm not familiarized with C++11 yet, so a question - is there a way to pass different arguments for this case? Because I thought about something like this, but how can I pass different arguments (as mentioned in the question)?

Comment: @KirilKirov: A lambda defined as `[&](...){...}` will capture all variables used inside the lambda by reference. So the functor created by `[&](){ object->execute(...); }` stores a reference to each variable mentioned in its body. This means you simply use a different lambda for each different invocation (it doesn't add that much typing afterall). Without C++11 this gets much uglyier, since you don't have inline functors and capturing variables is a pita. It might still be possible to make something readable with boost.Lambda (if that's even availible for your platform), but not as nice.

Comment: This is really great. +1 (accepted another answer, as this cannot be applied for C++03 :( )

Comment: @KirilKirov: Just to clarify: it can be applied to C++03 easily enough. The problem is just that the lack of lambda functions is probably going to make the code uglyier, though for simple cases like the one in the example `boost::bind` or `std::tr1::bind` would likely work well enough

Comment: Nice! I't high time for me to familiarize myself with boost, especially some "exotic" things like `boost::bind`. Thanks for the info.